# How can I bind two following events to one callback in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a widget and want its binding to handle two distinct events in order to call a function.

```
Widget.bind("<Event-1>", "<Event-2>", any_func)
```

and `any_func` may only be called if `<Event-1>` is followed by `<Event-2>`

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them together in one string, with or without whitespace between each event:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def insert_surprise(event):
    text.insert("insert", "surprise!")

text.bind("<Key-a> <Key-b>", insert_surprise)

root.mainloop()
```